# How to store the session values in array in cake php3

Tags: php, arrays, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cake php I am using session to store the values but every time the session is overwritten with new session value.so i am using array to store the session value and list  all the session values I am new to cake PHP 3 can any one help.

```
$session = $this->request->session();
$session->write('search', $repeats);
```

here i am creating an session in cake php

Comment: CakePHP handles sessions pretty well. If you can clarify your question we can try to help... specifically what you are looking to do and your intentions with it.

Comment: session name has to save in different names like $session1,$session2,$session3 by using array it is possible in cake php.to list the all the session values.

Comment: I think you should look into this: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cakephp allow you store the session values in array

```
//Sample:
$this->Session->write('User.email', 'abc@example.com');
$this->Session->write('User.phone', '090x108986');
$this->Session->write('User.site', 'http://rao5s.vn');
// Now you can read a array from Session
$arrUser = $this->Session->read('User');
```